# delete multiple records on EmberJS using {{input type="checkbox"}}

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to have an action that prints all the selected check-boxes on my table to the console.

in my controller I have

`removedSelected: function() {
            let selected = this.filterBy('isSelected', true);
            console.log(selected);
        }`

in my template file I have

`{{input type="checkbox" checked="isSelected"}}`

I have setup my controller to filter all the records that are "isSelected" in the table by using input helper on ember.

I am getting an error on the console which states `this.filterBy is not a function`

Do i need to setup an array to handle this first?

Below is more of the code for a better picture.

Thanks!

```
// templates/warranty/index.hbs

<div class="container">
<h4>List</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="control-group">
            {{#link-to 'warranty.new' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"}}New Claim{{/link-to}}
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" {{action "toggleMultiple"}}>Select</button>
            {{#if canDeleteMultiple}}<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"{{action "removedSelected" warranty}}>Delete Selected</button>{{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {{#if canDeleteMultiple}}<th>Select</th>{{/if}}
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Claim ID</th>
                <th>Claim Status</th>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>Issue Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each model as |warranty|}}
                <tr>
                    {{#if canDeleteMultiple}}{{input type="checkbox" checked="isSelected"}}{{/if}}
                    <td>{{#link-to 'warranty.edit' warranty.id class='btn btn-success btn-xs'}}Edit{{/link-to}}<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" {{action "deleteWarranty" warranty}}>Delete</button></td>
                    <td>{{warranty.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{warranty.claimStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{warranty.serialNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{warranty.issueDescription}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
</div>
```

```
// app/controllers/warranty/index.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

actions: {
    toggleMultiple() {
        this.toggleProperty('canDeleteMultiple');
    },

    removedSelected: function() {
        let selected = this.filterBy('isSelected', true);
        console.log(selected);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this way, you can check the twiddle (https://ember-twiddle.com/aa88cd0442ec0d2219e792d58ab8b703?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-component.hbs), same thing as mention by  kumkanillam,

in your index.hbs i used checkbox as a component,

```
{{checkbox-component isChecked=warranty.isSelected action=deleteItems index=index}}{{/if}}
```

and in controller actions,

```
removedSelected: function() {
  let selected = this.get('model').filterBy('isSelected', true);
  console.log(selected);
}
```

Comment: Yep this is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your hbs file,

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=warranty.isSelected }}
         OR
<input type="checkbox" checked={{warranty.isSelected}} onchange={{action (mut warranty.isSelected) value="target.checked" }}>
```

and in your controller,

```
removedSelected: function() {
        let selected = this.get('model').filterBy('isSelected', true);
        console.log(selected);
    }
```